# ratio of entries in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently writing an application that stores information to be queried from an API in a mongoDB. I want the app to do this in a smart matter by calculating a ratio by which it should determine what to query next.

the parts of the model that are of importance look like this:

```
collaborator: {type: String},
books: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
```

A collaborator is not unique (by design) and every collaborator entry has an array of objectIDs to which it refers.

What I want MongoDB to output is the collaborator that has the highest

```
(Sum of occurrences of collaborator name) / (sum of all books in his name)
```

The information that I have stored is the collaborators name, I want to query the API on the name of the books (so length of books can be 0), which I can only do one at a time. This way, I think, I will ask for the most important ones more often and once I have reached a certain quota for a collaborator it will ask for the next one.

If anyone has a better approach to this, you are very welcome.

This is my approach:

```
model.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$books"},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", bookcount: {$sum: 1} }},
    {$group: {_id: "$collaborator", useCases: { $sum: 1 }, totalBookCount: {$sum:"$bookCount"}  ?  {$sum:"$bookCount"}: 1 }},
    {$project: {_id: 1, from: 1, to: 1, quota: {$divide:["$useCases","$totalBookCount"]}}}])
    .sort({quota: -1})
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function (err,document) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        for(var i=0;i<document.length;i++){
            console.log(document[i]._id);
        }
     });
```

I do not get an error but an empty object. But, imho, my ternary operator should guarantee an output even if all book arrays are empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to step through the projection? Start with one pipeline, add another, etc. you should see the progression you expect (or not). Your pipeline is referring to `$collaborator` yet it wouldn't be present in the pipeline after the prior `$group`, would it?

Comment: And that JS ternary expression gets evaluated once, before the aggregation even starts.  Look at using `$cond` instead.

Comment: Doesnt $group have access to all fields? and mongoose does not support $cond (at least that is the error I keep getting)